# Is there a way to stream all audio from PC to Android via USB?

Tags: usb, audio

My headphones socket on my laptop is busted, and I'm wondering if I can stream all the audio (every sound the PC makes) from my laptop to my Android, so I can use the headphones connected to the phone.

It has to be by USB/Firewire, as my laptop doesn't have Bluetooth...

Answer (score 4):

You would better off getting a pair of USB headphones than streaming it to your phone.

Answer (score 4):

I've made an app called [AudioRelay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azefsw.audioconnect) which allows you to do that.
It's mainly used over Wifi but you can use your phone's **USB tethering** option to create a USB connection.

- First, [download](https://audiorelay.net) and start the server on your PC
- Launch the app on your phone
- Enable USB tethering (there's a shortcut inside the app)
- Click on the new server entry to start streaming!

You can check this [video (2:25)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MqoNgawbVE&feature=youtu.be&t=145) to see the feature in action :)

Comment: This works amazingly well! Thank you!!

Comment: This answer should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gV5BTYCqWb4) may help. It is through Wifi. If you have connected through USB or something else, you can play media files through your handset. There are apps for that. But, since you are asking for every computer sound, guess, you can do that only through WiFi. Hope that Youtube video helps! Thanks! Vote, if you find this helpful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a good solution for this to work over USB, but I have gotten it to work over wifi as well, with a much cheaper (free, or $3.99 if you want network compression) option with [SoundWire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree) than the Airfoil solution in Mannii88's video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SoundIt](https://soundit.app/) to stream audio from your computer to any other device easily, it's designed specifically for that.

It also lets you control the stream audio volume remotely.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of SoundIt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Found newer [solution](https://github.com/BreadFish64/AndroidUsbAudioDevice). It is quite difficult(I really mean it) to install but it is very powerful:

- It has very high quality of audio (I'm not sure, but it either lossless or very close to it).
- And it has really low latency (I can't properly test it since my smartphone bugged and has 200-300ms latency even on wired headphones)
- Uses only USB connection. It uses lower level USB protocols instead of usual network protocols.
- Currently only supports mono or stereo mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).